# Accessing the downloads API onChanged event

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is a web extension the only method of accessing the downloads API onChanged event? And, if so, I have a very basic question regarding web extensions.

My motivation for researching web extensions is that I'd like to access the downloads API in a progressive web app in order to better manage memory usage (revoking an object url only *after* a large text file generated on the client has been downloaded to the client) and to warn users of the app when their indexedDB database has changes that are more recent than the last time they saved the database to hard disk. The main item that I'm looking for is an event that let's me know the download has completed successfully on the client.

I've read over the introductory MDN web docs concerning extensions but I'm still missing something very basic, which is: is an extension something that a user must choose to install in their browser or is it something that I can include with the rest of the application files that can access the desired API and function properly on different browsers?

Thank you for any guidance and explanation you can provide.

Comment: Users must install extensions. Is usually a one click install but you can not force it using script

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know why there are APIs that are accessible only through extensions?

Comment: I've ben reading further and am even more confused. Is it correct that the API is available in the extension but doesn't make it available in the standard web page's javascript code? In other words, I still can't know if the file downloaded to the client and an extension is no help for my situation?

Comment: Short answer is you don't want any random web site accessing your files.